# put JLabel on top of the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, graphics2d, paintcomponent

When I run my code then `JLabel` is looking behind the `JPanel`. Why this is happening? I have to show the label on top of panel.

### Code

```
public class ColoredRect extends JPanel{
          
      public double x, y, width, height;  
      public JLabel name;
      
      public ColoredRect(double x,double y,String label)
      {
          name = new JLabel(label);
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.width = 100;
          this.height =40;
           
          setLocation((int)x,(int)y);
          setSize((int)width,(int)height);
          setBackground(Color.red);
          
          add(name);
       }

       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // Draw all the rects in the ArrayList.
        super.paintComponent(g);  // Fills with background color, white.
        name.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        name.setVisible(true);
        name.setLocation((int)x+3, (int)y+3);
        name.setSize(20, 20);
        name.repaint();
       }
       
       public void setnewPosition(double x, double y)
      {
          this.x =x;
          this.y =y;
          this.setLocation((int)x,(int) y);
          repaint();
      }
}
```

Comment: I think the Z index of JLabel is less than that of JPanel so try to increase the Z index of JLabel

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why exactly are you extending `JPanel` what exactly you are doing inside your `paintComponent(...)` method, you not drawing anything on it with those lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never used the [setOpaque()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque%28boolean%29), method to set it's value as being `OPAQUE`. Here have a look at this example, see how you draw on the `JPanel` and add `JLabel` on it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelPaintingExample
{
    private ColouredRectangle cRect, cRect1, cRect2;    
    private Rectangle rect;

    public PanelPaintingExample()
    {       
        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 30);
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {   
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Panel Painting Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

        cRect = new ColouredRectangle(Color.RED, "LABEL 1"
                                               , Color.WHITE
                                               , rect);
        cRect1 = new ColouredRectangle(Color.BLUE, "LABEL 2"
                                               , Color.WHITE
                                               , rect);
        cRect2 = new ColouredRectangle(Color.MAGENTA, "LABEL 3"
                                               , Color.WHITE
                                               , rect);                                     

        frame.add(cRect);
        frame.add(cRect1);
        frame.add(cRect2);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new PanelPaintingExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ColouredRectangle extends JPanel
{
    private Color backColour;
    private Color foreColour;
    private String text;
    private Rectangle rect;

    private JLabel label;

    public ColouredRectangle(Color b, String text
                                     , Color f, Rectangle rect)
    {
        this.backColour = b;
        this.foreColour = f;
        this.text = text;
        this.rect = rect;

        label = new JLabel(this.text, JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(backColour);
        label.setForeground(foreColour);

        add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(200, 30));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(backColour);
        g.fillRect((int)rect.getX(), (int)rect.getY()
                              , (int)rect.getWidth()
                              , (int)rect.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what text you want to add to your JLabel, you set the size of the label in `paintComponent(Graphics g)` to be 20 px wide and 20 px height. 20 px width isn't very wide. Try to increase the label width if you have a label text longer than a couple of chars.

Answer (score 1):

I checked entire code and executed

actually the label is on the top of the JPanel but it location gone to out of the jpanel boundary    when you calling/object creating for "ColoredRect()" pass the parameters as minimum as

```
//pass the values and check it
ColoredRect(77,17,"string");
```

because location of label is x+3 and y+3 means 77+3+label width 20=100;        x+3 means 17+3+ label heigth 20=40,

if you pass more than 77,17 the label location out of panel boundary

**OR change the**

```
this.width = 1000;
this.height =500;
```